# control elasticsearch configuration in spring-data setup

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I startup elasticsearch via XML configuration like this:

```
<elasticsearch:node-client id="client" local="true"/>
```

Now I need more control on configuration e.g. setting the index files location. How can I achieve this? Can I pass parameter somehow or do I need to specify a config-file location using environment property `-Des.config=`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use @Setting(settingPath = "elasticsearch.properties") in your config class and inside the file set the path.data property.

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29594496/679471)