# How to set the data directory of ElasticSearch with Spring Boot

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot

My problem is similar to [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687545/control-elasticsearch-configuration-in-spring-data-setup)
I have a spring boot appplication where I save some document in elasticsearch. The index is created in a data dir in the current directory each time. I want to change this default path to a given one. How can I do that? A such a simple task takes hours to find it out.

I tried many things:

1. `@Setting(setting="/data/elasticsearch")`
2. In an elasticseacrh.properties and `application.properties` file:

   1. `path.data`
   2. `spring.data.elasticsearch.path.data`

Without any luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Adding the path with the configuration file in my application class:

   ```
   @Setting(settingPath = "/home/topic/src/main/resources/elasticsearch.properties")
   ```
2. Set the path.data property in the file:

   ```
   path.data=/Users/mimis/Desktop/data
   ```

Did the trick.

**Update**:
With Spring Boot 1.3.0 we can add any Elasticsearch property in the application properties files by using the `spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.*` prefix. For example:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.data.path=/path/to/data
```

Comment: Using Spring Boot 1.3.0, and "spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.data.path" or "spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.data" is not working... is this really supported? Haven't found decent answer on the subject.

Comment: currently i use spring boot 2.6. In my applications/properties files located in the resource folder i have the setting spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.data and it works

Comment: yaml configuration didnt work for me but the .properties file configurations works.

Answer (score 4):

For me (Grails / Spring Boot 1.3.3) the following configuration works better:

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.data=/path/to/data
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.logs=/path/to/logs
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue and none of the answers provided solved it , the accept answer got the wrong property which is

```
 spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.data=/path/to/data
```

not

```
 spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.data.path=/path/to/data
```

Though with this value you will have a problem because you are writing into the root of your machine ( a mac in my case) which needs an access rights which I cannot provide so the elasticsearch template will fail to start, instead you need to set the value to

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.data=path/to/data
```

This will create the path from the context of your application which is the root directory of your project which the application already has rights to write to it